# How to deploy Laravel4 on heroku?

Tags: heroku, laravel-4, heroku-toolbelt

I am using Laravel4 and mysql. I want deploy this application in Heroku.

Not sure what steps need to followed to deploy it on Heroku. Because I am using

php artisan commands to create db, seed data into the db.

For eg:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

Please guide me

Thank all

Comment: i am getting this error Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Comment: you should include errors in your question

Comment: i am not getting any error only empty page when i access app

Comment: https://www.heroku.com/features <~ it does not support PHP. o.O?

Comment: Try [this buildpack](http://blog.enge.me/post/a-comprehensive-tutorial-for-deploying-laravel-4-on-heroku)